# iOS push notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, tokens

De repente no estoy recibiendo notificaciones push a mi aplicación, sin embargo no se ha realizado ningún cambio. El error que estoy recibiendo es:

`Fail to hand off a notification to APNS for the device token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx after a few retries. Please make sure the APNS SSL certificate for the application is correctly generated and the environment i.e. sandbox vs production, is configured correctly.`

Lo veo todo correcto pero ni desde el Postman ni desde la app me llegan las notificaciones, sin embargo desde aquí https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/notifications/ si me llegan.

¿Alguna idea? Ya he visitado muchas páginas pero no veo que a nadie le de el mismo error que a mí.

Actualización:

- Los certificados son válidos, no caducan hasta dentro de un mes.
- Esta es la configuración en SAP Mobile Services[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Compruebo que el identificador del equipo es el mismo
- En certificados, identificadores y perfiles, tengo una key y la key id es la mismo que en SAP mobile services.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- También lo he probado en otro dispositivo y sigue sin llegar.
- Tengo los entlitements en xcode así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ideas muchas, pero en español todas. Igual que la pregunta debería estar también en dicho idioma :) Por favor utiliza el enlace [edit] y tradúcela.

Comment: @Benito-B Perdón no me di cuenta que era stackoverflow en español. Qué ideas tienes?

Comment: @Benito-B si tienes algunas ideas me vendría muy bien...ya no se que más probar :(. Actualicé la pregunta con las cosas que he probado

Comment: Las capturas indican que estás usando el ambiente de Sandbox, el certificado es válido para ese ambiente? Si pruebas con otro device token tampoco llega?